# Как убрать лишнее сверху и снизу картинки

Tags: html, jquery, css

Использую плагин fengyuanchen/cropperjs. Как сделать так, чтобы не отображался задний фон сверху и снизу картинки?

[image: Пример]

```
$("#crop_img").cropper({
 viewMode: 1,
 dragMode: "move",
 autoCropArea: 0,
 minCanvasWidth: 500,                       
 restore: false,
 guides: false,
 movable: false,
 highlight: false,
 cropBoxMovable: true,
 cropBoxResizable: false,
 zoomable: false,
 zoomOnTouch: false,
 zoomOnWheel: false,
 built: function() {
  $("#crop_img").cropper("setCropBoxData", { left: 0, top: 0, width: 100, height: 100 });
 }
});
```

Пример с используемыми опциями плагина: https://jsfiddle.net/zkbnc10a/5/

Comment: может img добавить display: block?

Comment: да, спасибо, вроде так работает

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

https://jsfiddle.net/zkbnc10a/6/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#crop_img").cropper({
    viewMode: 3,
    dragMode: "move",
    autoCropArea: 0,
    minCanvasWidth: 300,
    restore: false,
    guides: false,
    movable: false,
    highlight: false,
    cropBoxMovable: true,
    cropBoxResizable: false,
    zoomable: false,
    zoomOnTouch: false,
    zoomOnWheel: false,
    built: function() {
      $("#crop_img").cropper("setCropBoxData", {
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        width: 100,
        height: 100
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#crop_img {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img id="crop_img" src="https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/img/picture.jpg">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```